# run newman test from browser

Tags: python, node.js, postman, newman

How can I run the newman test from Browser?
Can we do in Python or is there any option in node to do this?
Sorry, really I am not a developer. Need your support and help please

#### mytest.js

```js
const newman = require('newman');
newman.run({
        collection: require('./Tests.postman_collection.json'),
        environment: require('./Test.postman_environment.json'),
        reporters: ['htmlextra', 'cli'],
        reporter: {
          htmlextra: {
            export: './Reports/Feb25.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .on('start', function(err, args) { // on start of run, log to console
        console.log('Running collection for you...');
      })
      .on('done', function(err, summary) {
        if (err || summary.error) {
          console.error('collection run encountered an error.');
        } else {
          console.log('collection run completed.');
        }
      });
```

Comment: Are you able to share some more information or context. Do you want to have a button or something that links to the script? Not really sure what you're asking. :)

Comment: @DannyDainton 
Hi Danny, yes a button on html page to invoke my newman test as above mytest.js

Comment: You _could_ do it but it's not easy to do as Nodejs and the browser are 2 different environments. I would have thought that you would need to create a Node API which renders a button on a HTML page. It would then need hooking together somehow.